# How to fix Fatal Error after consecutive calls to MySQLi_Connect?

Tags: php, xampp

I had to learn some PHP to set up some tables of holiday images. I originally did this in an earlier version of WAMP using MySQL and it worked fine.

I am now faced  with updating the tables and countries using the current version of XAMPP (converting all the calls to MySQLi).

This is where my problem begins. I get the "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in.....". I have searched this site and some others for the answer to my specific error scenario, without success.

I am running the latest XAMPP under Win 10. I have 3 files:

Generate_Tables_DE - I also have a similar one for EN. It just defines the output language.

```
      <?php
      echo "<br>include Generate_Tables.php<br><br>";
      include '../Generate_Tables.php';
      echo "<br />Generating Tables - German<br /><br />";
      Generate_Tables("#FFFFFF", "DE"); 
      ?>
```

It calls:
Generate_Tables - This sets up the actual table in the DB, there is one for each country:

```
      <?php
      function Generate_Tables($BgCol, $Land)
      {
      echo $BgCol . "   " . $Land . "<BR />"; 
      include("../Create_Table.php");

      $Sum_Total = 0;
      $Sum_Total += Create_Table("Thailand", $BgCol, $Land); 
      $Sum_Total += Create_Table("India", $BgCol, $Land); 
      $Sum_Total += Create_Table("Indonesia", $BgCol, $Land); 
      echo "Sum Total of all images = " . $Sum_Total . "<br /><br />";
      }
      ?>
```

This, then calls:
Create_Table - This is where the problem occurs:

```
  <?php
  function Create_Table($Name, $bgCol, $Land)
  {

  require_once("../constants.php");
  require_once("../functions.php");
  $DBconn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
  if (!$DBconn) {
      die("<BR />Database DBconn failed: " . mysql_error());
  }
  $db_select = mysqli_select_db($DBconn,'Images');
   if (!$db_select) {
      die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
   }

  /* Some processing */

  if (mysqli_close($DBconn) == FALSE) 
    {
        echo "<BR/>End DBconn failed";
    }
  return ($array_count);
  }
  ?>
```

The "Thailand" table is generated with no problem and the "India" table is started, but quits with the 30 second time out on the MySQLi_connect command.

I have tried variations of the connect, such as including the DB name in the connect and deleting the MySQLi_select. Nothing cures the problem.

What differentiates this from all the answers that I've found is that it is only on the second iteration of Create_Table that the error occurs. If I remove the "Thailand" call from Generate_Table, "India" works, but "Indonesia" now has the problem. 
I have searched through tutorials and manuals, but there seems to be nothing that I'm doing wrong.
Can anyone help? Please?

P.S. Sorry if the whole thing is a bit primitive, it is my first foray into PHP.

Comment: Please see below answer. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the SQL requests you use (I  believe they are supposed to be in the "/* some processing */" part. Might be an issue with the SQL queries sent, such as a carthesian product, ...

Comment: Did the answer helped you? Kindly accept it or upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Change the `max_execution_time` config on your `php.ini`

or you may just change the execution time upon runtime on that specific script by:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Comment: This is not, ATM, a proper answer since it might hide the issue instead of fixing it.

Comment: I based my answer on the error given. And based on the scripts he put in, it seems that it performs the logic that he wants but is just lacking on the execution time. But I understand your downvote, though the OP must clarify his question too.

Comment: Without the set of SQL queries ran, we cannot know for sure that this is merely a timeout issue. If one of the queries isn't good, the script might take forever to complete.

Comment: @NaeiKinDus, yeah that's why I want the OP to clarify his question too. :) But on the current question, my answer does suffice.